# heroku run rails db:migrate Running rails

Tags: database, heroku, error-handling

E:\app\sample_app>heroku run rails db:migrate
Running rails db:migrate on ? evening-hamlet 67682... up, run.6550 (Free)
D,[2018-09-11T14:11:30.600986 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(4573329190602081420)
D, [2018-09-11T14:11:30.630504 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.5ms)SELECT "schema_migrati
ons"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
D, [2018-09-11T14:11:30.647389 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE
"ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-09-11T14:11:30.661078 #4] DEBUG -- :   (1.7ms)  BEGIN
D, [2018-09-11T14:11:30.664560 #4] DEBUG -- :  (1.8ms)  COMMIT
D, [2018-09-11T14:11:30.668555 #4] DEBUG -- :    (3.6ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(4573329190602081420)

Comment: Please add more information to this question. Other than this log line, there's no other description about what sort of answer you're looking for from the community.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this $heroku run rake db:migrate
not $heroku run rails db:migrate

Comment: i did but now i am getting other error E:\app\sample_app>heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on ? evening-hamlet-67682... / starting, run.8334 (Free)
Running rake db:migrate on ? evening-hamlet-67682... up, run.8334 (Free)
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Error loading the 'postgresql' Active Record adapter. Missing a
gem it depends on? pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.

Comment: Add this line to your gem file gem 'pg', :group => :production